# Concatenation of strings in unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have an input like below in a variable in Unix

```
x=1 48 38 39 45
```

I want to attach brackets `()` to the above so that it acts like an array, so the output should be

```
x=(1 48 38 39 45)
```

What is the easy way to do in Unix?

Comment: `x="($x"; x="$x)"` done.

Comment: Did you mean `x="1 48 38 39 45"`? You need quotes to make it a single string.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamar, all you need to do is append a parenthesis to the beginning contents of `x` and then again at the end. The dead-bang simple way to do it is:

```
x="($x"
```

followed by:

```
x="$x)"
```

Now `x` will have a parenthesis at each end.

You can do it all at once as well:

```
x="($x)"
```

You can also use the `+=` operator to append at the end of a string, so a two-part incorporating that operator would be:

```
x="($x"
x+=")"
```

Same result.

Comment: Thank you, this works but didn't solve my problem. I created the above string using tr command so that it will act like array so I thought brackets are missing but I don't why can't I pick the individual values. when I do echo my output is (1 48 38 39 45) and when I try to use echo "${x[3]}" I get an empty string. Do you know why?

Comment: If you are creating an array, then it must be created by using `(..)` at the time of creation. If the above results from a `tr` command, then do `x=( $(your tr command) )`  Where `$(...)` is called *command substitution*.

Comment: @Lamar I presume that fixed it for you. If not, let me know. Also, if that solves your issue, please mark my answer as answering your question so this question doesn't continue to bounce around in the unanswered queue.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Your comment probably answered his question better than the answer does.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sorry, It actually didn't work. May be I will simplify it more. I have numbers separated by newline in variable X which needs to be converted into array so that I'm able to pick up individual values.     X = 1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n and I used tr function to convert them into array tr '\n' ' ' the way you suggested but didn't work for me.

Comment: @DavidC.RankinI wrote a for loop with append +=() to an array and it is working, Thanks for your valuable time and help

Comment: @Lamar - Glad it helped. Don't forget to select my answer as answering your question. You do that by putting clicking at the top left of my answer. Otherwise this question stays in the "Unanswered" queue forever.